# Solving equation - Overflow error

Tags: equation, sympy

Basically I just want to solve `k`. Note that the equation equals to `1.12`

```
import math
from sympy import *

a = 1.45
b = 4.1
c = 14.0

al = math.log(a, 2)
bl = math.log(b, 2)
cl = math.log(c, 2)

k = symbols('k')

print solve(Eq(1/k**al + 1/k**bl + 1/k**cl, 1.12), k)
```

This raises `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

Solution using other libraries welcomed too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using numerical values, I am assuming that you are looking for a numerical solution. In that case, you should not use solve, because it tries to find a symbolic solution. The issue here is that it converts these floating point exponents into rational exponents, which have very large numerators and denominators, and it then at some point tries to make polynomials of degree corresponding to those large numbers, which is where it fails.

To solve numerically, you can use `nsolve`.

```
>>> print nsolve(Eq(1/k**al + 1/k**bl + 1/k**cl, 1.12), 2)
1.82427203413783
```

It's better to use numeric libraries like SciPy if you are interested in numeric solutions, though. You can use `lambdify` to convert your SymPy expressions into functions more suited for libraries like SciPy that use NumPy arrays.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! What does this `2` at the end of the line stand for? Is it always the value of `2`? In numerous docs I saw there the symbol put, like here: `k`.

Comment: In `solve`, you you pass the Symbol or list of Symbols to be solved for. In `nsolve`, you can only solve for one Symbol at at time (because the rest has to be numeric), so there is no need to pass that. But what it does need is an initial guess. That's what the `2` is. If you have an equation with multiple solutions, you can find others by providing guesses near the solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known [issue](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=3887).

You may try

```
solve(Eq(1/k**al + 1/k**bl + 1/k**cl, 1.12), k, rational=False)
```

Comment: Thanks but it raises `No algorithms are implemented to solve equation...`

Comment: @nutship That maybe relating to something else other than code syntax you asked. Maybe your equation is too complex. Please take a look the solvers [doc](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.3/tutorial/solvers.html).